# Unable to get the value from a query with WHERE Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the Total Sum of values from a table. Query works without WHERE Clause, but i need to get the total sum per user. Like user ABC has 100USD and user BDC has 200USD. Here is the code

```
$PWithdrawls = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM withdraw WHERE status='Pending'");
$S_NO = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PWithdrawls)) {
    $S_NO++;

    $posted_by          = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$row['seller_id']);
    $user_ad            = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posted_by);

    $TotalOrders_Amount = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM orders WHERE userId=".$row['seller_id']);
    $sum_amount         = mysqli_fetch_assoc($TotalOrders_Amount);
    $sum                = $sum_amount['total'];
```

And here is my call

```
<td>$<?php echo $sum; ?></td>
```

Here is DB
[image]

Comment: Are you calling `<td>$<?php echo $sum; ?></td>` inside or outside the loop?

Comment: Also, if you just need totals per user, all three queries could be replaced by a single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was calling the wrong variable. userId was not in my table, it was seller_id. So correct query was

```
$TotalOrders_Amount = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM orders WHERE seller_id=".$row['seller_id']);
```

Thanks to everyone. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Think you have error in your SQL Query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM orders WHERE userId=".$row['seller_id'] GROUP BY userId LIMIT 1
```

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get actual `SUM`. Also you can get all users with Total, there is no need to second query:

```
SELECT u.*, SUM(o.amount) AS total 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.userId = u.id)
GROUP BY u.userId
```

This should get you entire user row + total of their orders.

Comment: There is no need to group when filtering by a single user id, so your first part is incorrect. However, I agree this whole business could be done with a single query. Depends on what the OP really needs.

Comment: If you filtering multiple orders, there needs to be GROUP BY or you will for example 500 rows with same SUM in all of them

Comment: [No, you won't](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f3c12/1).

Comment: You're right. MySQL is handling this on it's own.... i just tried it. More you know....